# What can I use to make n (4) analogue values selectable by a digital pin?

Tags: arduino, digital-logic, analog, integrated-circuit

Using an arudino nano as the micro controller, I would like to read a few voltages around my project board.

These values are being read by way of a simple voltage divider circuit for values up to 25v, using 30KΩ and 7.5KΩ resistors on each point I want to read.

My micro-controller only has 1 analogue port free but has many digital ports free. I was wondering what IC would I use to make the voltage to read from any specific sensor selectable via a digital pin and software?

I am very new to this work, so your kindness and patience is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Use a multiplexer.

Comment: 74HC4052 would do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can use a 4:1 analogue multiplexer such as a TMUX1204 or similar device. Do a search for Analogue Multiplexers and you will find many suitable parts ...